# Is there any Azure Cache/database supporting multi-region automatic failover

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-redis-cache

We have one webapp running on Azure, which pushes data to Azure Redis, then we have an on-prem component which reads that data from Azure redis and processes that. 
Recently due to Azure region failure that Azure Redis went down. Web app and my on-prem component was not able to contact Azure redis.

How can I make sure zero down time for my web app to access Azure redis ?
Redis-GeoRelication doesn't solves my problem as it is unideirectional, and Manual failover. Also my web app and on-prem component need to know both redis endpoint, and contact accrondignly. which is not seemless.

Azure redis doesn't support cluster having shards in multiple region.

**So my requirement is, Web-app and on-prem component both need to contain one cache/database endpoint ( without having any knowledge about the replication of the cache/database). if primary cache/db fails then, that endpoint should automatically goes to replicated cache or DB.**

As per Documentation from Azure, it doesn't seem Azure Redis is correct fit for this requirment, is there any other Azure component which fits this requiremnet.

Had a look to Azure sql with failover group. As per documentation, "you can configure a grace period that controls the time between the detection of the outage and the failover itself. It is possible that traffic manager initiates the endpoint failover before the failover group triggers the failover of the database. In that case the web application cannot immediately reconnect to the database. But the reconnections will automatically succeed as soon as the database failover completes." . We can set that grace period to 1 hour (minimum) .

**So it means with Azure sql also. In case of failure of one db server, my web application will not be able to write to db for atleast 1 hour, Is my understanding correct ?**

Answer (score 2):

[Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/) and [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction) both support single endpoint and HA across regions, you might want to look into those.

Those are not caches, but they do allow for a single endpoint and failover

Comment: Are you taking about Azure SQL failover group? some configuration which says "grace period".Minimum time for grace period can be set is 1 hour.As per Azure Documentation" you can configure a grace period that controls the time between the detection of the outage and the failover itself. It is possible that traffic manager initiates the endpoint failover before the failover group triggers the failover of the database. In that case the web application cannot immediately reconnect to the database. But the reconnections will automatically succeed as soon as the database failover completes" .

Comment: you can forcé failover if you detect failure